no module named error even though I already installed the modules
I am trying to integrate CHATGPT by open ai to my discord server.
this is the code:
import discord
import openai

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

# Discord and Openai
DISCORD_TOKEN = "key"
openai.api_key = "key"

# Initialize a client object for Discord bot
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Function that sends message to OpenAI API and gets response
async def ask_gpt(message):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": message.content}
        ]
    )
    answer = response.choices[0].message.content
    return answer

# Listener that checks for messages in Discord
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Ignore messages from the bot itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # Sends message to OpenAI API
    response = await ask_gpt(message)
    # Sends response back to channel
    await message.channel.send(response)


# Start the bot
client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)

I'm using pycharm.
IT has errors:
no module named 'discord'
no module named 'openai'
When I try to run it the terminal says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My Computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Scripts\Discord_bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

I already installed the modules using "pip install discord" and "pip install openai"
I even restarted my pc in hoping that it would be fixed but no luck :V. I'm an absolute beginner in programming in fact I just copy and pasted this from a video on youtube.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/lyBUH.png)
Tried restarting my pc.
Tried using Visual Code Studio.
Checked if the modules are installed. CMD and pyCharm terminal says it is installed.

Hello @Mark first, please try to not use images, instead copy and paste the error. The problem you're facing, 99% of the time, is related to virtual environment.

I had this problem sometimes because pip wasn’t using the right Python (e.g. I had 3.12 as python3 and pip installed it into the 3.11 site-packages directory).
Instead of using your current aliases, you can be extremely explicit:

Instead using the pip or pip3 command, use python3 -m pip.
Use which python3 to find the absolute path for your desired Python installation. In my case it’s /usr/bin/python3 (I don’t use venvs), but if it’s in a venv in might be something like .venv/bin/python3. Pass this as the --python argument to pip (before install). This will force pip to use that Python.
If pip complains “normal site-packages is not writable”, try again with sudo.

For example:
sudo python3 -m pip --python .venv/bin/python3 install openai discord


Activate your env



Platform
Shell
Command to activate virtual environment




POSIX
bash/zsh
$ source <venv>/bin/activate



fish
$ source <venv>/bin/activate.fish



csh/tcsh
$ source <venv>/bin/activate.csh



PowerShell
$ <venv>/bin/Activate.ps1


Windows
cmd.exe
C:\> <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat



PowerShell
PS C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1



